# why is my view control categorized column sometimes wrapping or not "overlapping" the other columns

Tags: xpages

I have multiple views with categorization.  Sometimes the view displays as it should in native Notes but other times the categorized column text wraps under the twistie and other times the column is wide as if it weren't categorized taking too much room up on the page.  I'm using simple views.  Can someone shed some light, I've compared and looked all over to find what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Categorized columns "overlap" if you don't show "total" columns.

As soon as you show a total column in xp:viewPanel - categories are put in separate table columns and don't overlap anymore.